# How to change a $scope variable outside the controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to change a `$scope.outsidescope` outside the controller. I am using `$routeProvider` to route and change controller. The `$scope.outsidescope` is present outside the `ng-view`.

My Question is How can i change a `$scope.value` outside of the `ng-view`.

Sample Code:

```
<html ng-app="Myapp">
 .......
<body>
   <div>
     {{outsidescope}}
   </div>
   <div class="" data-ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular Code:

```
var app = angular.module('Myapp', ['ngRoute']).
   config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
    .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/home4.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/pages/404'
     })
 }]);

app.controller('PageCtrl', ['$cookies',function ($scope) {
   $scope.outsidescope = 'Some thing.';
}
```

Comment: <div ng-controller="PageCtrl">
          {{outsidescope}}
          </div>

Use the controller name on the div

Comment: Still not clear what you are wanting to do exactly. Your layout and explanation are oversimplified. Using a service is the typical best approach to sharing data across controllers.

Comment: @charlietfl Yaa after lots of research i get that it will be done by service. But when i add a controller to the first div. it shows angular error.

Comment: what is error and based on what code?

Comment: @charlietfl Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Comment: Well tht can be caused even by simple syntax errors and all you gave was the error title but not the full message. Error messages  have meaning.

Comment: @charlietfl Hey I edited my question with error link Please check it.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't post the message and need to post all that garbage that we can't click on? Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: The question is really unclear. Where is the `scope.value` in your template? And which template? What about this `$scope.outsidescope` in your code? Your code example and your description of the problem not linked at all.

Comment: @djxak I really sorry about that. I want to change `$scope.outsidescope` out side the controller how can i do that ?

Comment: But what does `out side the controller` even mean? If it's from another controller as already mentioned share data using a service. You simply aren't providing enough details for any part of this

Comment: @charlietfl I am using PageCtrl controller. So i can use all $scope variable inside the templateurl `partials/home4.html`. But my need is to change/edit the value of  `{{outsidescope}}`. How can i do that ?

Comment: Use another controller to wrap `{{outsidescope}}`, or use a directive and use a service to share data with `PageCtrl`

Comment: @charlietfl Actually I am new to angularjs. So can you please give me any reference to know how to do that ?

Comment: Add `ng-controller` to element and study some tutorials and/or other posts on this site  on how to use services for sharing. there are lots of tutorials around on how it works

Answer (score 0):

Use $rootScope instead of $scope to share data across the application. But creating a custom service is the best approach.

Comment: This is  frowned upon practice and there is rarely any need to put things in $rootScope unless they are needed globally

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to share data between controllers

1) Binding data in **$rootScope**
2) Binding data in **services**

Answer (score -2):

Its not Possible to change $scope outside the controller because it's not available outside the controller.

If you want to do so you can use parent scope which is $rootScope you can access this anywhere in your application.

But As per you requirement its better to use ng-bind instead of expression and in your router for every url you can call s resolve to assign the value to your this value.

Comment: `ng-bind` and `{{}}` do exact same thing as far as directional binding. Read the docs.

Comment: `Typically, you don't use ngBind directly, but instead you use the double curly markup like {{ expression }} which is similar but less verbose.`

Comment: yes But of you user {{expression}} and when you load the page it will show you the {{expression}} untill the value is not assigned and with ng-bind it will show nothing untill value is assign. So as I think its better to use ng-bind.

Comment: But that is completely different issue than what you stated in answer which was very misleading and non of this is relevant to OP's question. Proper use of `ng-cloak` and directives avoids the issue also